# Best methods and ways of protecting website

Tags: php, mysql, file, security, web

I'm almost ready to transfer my website to my web host, but before that, I'd like to make it as well-protected as possible. I've heard about MySQL injection and other problems that you can face, how would I protect my site, the MySQL databases and files from them?

I'm going to change from the mysql extension to either mysqli or PDO, which do you recommend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use PDO personally, its better than mysqli. If you dont know mysql injection is where you insert raw data into a query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" .$_GET['user']. "' AND password='" .$_GET['password']. "'";
```

Without sanitizing the inputs, if someone enters admin as the username and `' OR '1'='1` as the password the query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='admin' AND password='' OR '1'='1'
```

This causes the query to ignore the password and log you in as admin as long as 1=1 which it always does. Just using mysql, you can use `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user'])` to escape anything that could potentially affect the query like ' would become \' which the database would understand. Note that the attacker can do much worse things than logging in as an admin, for example they could delete your entire database structure with the drop command and commenting out the code after it, or actually affect your web server with really weird shellcode.

With something like PDO or MySQLi, prepared statements tell the database first what the query is going to be, then send the informaton instead of actually having it in the query like so:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
$stm->execute(array($_GET['user'], $_GET['password']));
```

Edit: One more thing, I think it is possible to still do mysql injections using pdo but I have no idea how that works so I'd suggest do a bit more research and see if you can find anything.